# How to access to the number of enveloppes per user per time period on Docusign?

Tags: python, docusignapi

I would like to simply access the number of enveloppes (per user and per period) for billing purposes. Any idea how to do it in a fast way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably best is to set up an account-level webhook via the Connect feature.

Your software can then be notified anytime a user in your account sends an envelope. You can add the information to your own BI (Business Intelligence) system and create derivative reports such as envelopes per user per week, etc.